# Clarification on a proof involving cluster point

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Definition of cluster point- Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. A point $c\in\mathbb{R}$ is a cluster point of $A$ if for evert $\delta>0$ there exists at least one point $x\in A$, $x\neq c$ such that $|x-c|<\delta$.

Theorem- A number $c\in\mathbb{R}$ is a cluster point of a subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$ iff there exists a sequence $(a_n)$ in A such that lim$(a_n)=c$ and $a_n \neq c$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. I'm stuck on understanding the foward direction.

Proof: $(\rightarrow)$"If $c$ is a cluster point of $A$ then for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ the $\frac{1}{n}$-neighborhood $V_{\frac{1}{n}}(c)$ contains atleast one point $a_n\in A$ distinct from $c$. Then  $a_n\in A$, $a_n \neq c$, and $|a_n-c|<\frac{1}{n}$ implies  lim$(a_n)=c$."

What I understand is that if we let $\delta>0$ then it follows by the Archimdean property that there exists a $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{k}<\delta$. It follows if $n\geq k$ then $\frac{1}{n}<\frac{1}{k}<\delta$. Since $c$ is a cluster point there exists a $x_{n}\in A$ where $x_{n}\neq c$ such that $|x_{n}-c|<\frac{1}{n}<\delta$ since $\frac{1}{n}>0$. Thus by the definition of convergence we have $lim (a_n)=c$. Would this be a correct way of understanding the proof to this theorem?

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but what's the difference between a cluster point and a limit point?

Comment: Basically your proving the limit point is $c$.

Comment: So a limit point and a cluster point are exactly the same thing?  Does anyone know why both terms exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you're thinking about it too hard. For any positive number $\delta$, you're promised one point $x =x _\delta$ different from $c$. In particular, for any $n\in\Bbb N$, $n^{-1}$ is a positive number, so you're promised a point $x=x_n$ different from $c$. And since $x_n\in(c-n^{-1},c+n^{-1})$, we have $$|x_n-c|<n^{-1}$$ so that $x_n\to c$. You are right that to show that $x_n\to c$ we use the Archiemedean property of the real numbers. Given $\varepsilon >0$ all we need to do is take $n$ large enough so that $n^{-1}<\varepsilon$.

Comment: i just don't get the part about the $\frac{1}{n}$ neighborhood. Why it works and is it from the archimdean property? Could I have used another neighborhood instead?

Comment: @user60887 Here we're just "letting" $\delta=1,1/2,1/3,\ldots$ and for each of those $\delta$s getting a point $x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots$ with the properties the definition ensures.

Comment: @user60887 you can use any neighborhoods in particular you can use those that Pedro are suggesting. The idea is that this gives some points indexed by $n$, ie a sequence.

Comment: And $a_n$ converges to $c$ since $\frac{1}{n}$ is convergent?

Comment: @user60887 Well, it is convergent, but moreover it converges to $0$. That's indispensable.

Comment: @user60887 remember, given two sequences $0\leq a_n\leq b_n$, if $b_n\to 0$ then $a_n\to 0$. And, for any sequence $(a_n)$, $a_n\to l$ if and only if $\left|a_n-l\right|\to 0$

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is finding another $1/n$ when there's already one provided in the proof.

I will just list a variety of points here that will hopefully illuminate what's going on.

(1) A cluster point $c$ of a subset $A$ is one that, no matter how small an open interval you put around it, will have at least one other point of $A$ nearby inside that interval.

(2) In the proof, a decreasing sequence of neighbourhoods is being used to construct a sequence that converges to $c$. This means that you can choose a point that is not $c$ for each $n$. It doesn't matter whether or not the sequence you're building has a pattern, it's terms are none the less getting closer and closer to $c$.

(3) For each $n$, you can pick one element of $A$ that is not $c$ and call it $a_n$. Given that this $a_n$ is inside $V_{1/n}$ you have $|a_n - c|<1/n$ and this is true for all $n$.

(4) By the convergence of the sequence $\{1/n\}$ to zero, given a $\delta>0$, there is an $N$ so that for all $n>N$, $1/n < \delta$. This is what implies $|a_n - c| < 1/n < \delta$ for all $n>N$.

(5) Thus, given a $\delta > 0$ there exists an $N$ with $n>N$ implies $|a_n - c| < 1/n < \delta$ and this gives convergence of $a_n$ because it's true no matter how small your $\delta$.

Comment: yeah parts 4 and 5 is what I kind of was trying to explain but it makes sense where you said $\frac{1}{n}$ converges.